# How to use ZTE AX326 Modem on Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, usb-modem, zte

I want to use zte ax 326 modem on ubuntu, but this is not working. 
can you help me how can I use usb modem on ubuntu 10.10, please.

thanks.

Comment: Please update your question with type of problem your are facing. The modem is for CDMA/GSM access and what you have tried. Did you provided any user id & password.

Comment: I try usb-modswitch, but it is not work.

Answer (score -1):

there is an answer for that ;-)

http://unix-master.blogspot.com/2013/02/zte-ax326-4g-modem-drivers-for-linux.html